# How can I replace substring from string by a list in a column dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to replace substrings in a column value in dataframe

Example: I have this column 'code' in a dataframe (in really, the dataframe is very large)

```
3816R(motor) #I need '3816R'
97224(Eletro)
502812(Defletor)
97252(Defletor)
97525(Eletro)
5725 ( 56)
```

And I have this list to replace the values:

```
list = ['(motor)', '(Eletro)', '(Defletor)', '(Eletro)', '( 56)']
```

I've tried a lot of methods, like:

```
df['code'] = df['code'].str.replace(list, '')
```

And regex= True, but anyone method worked to remove the substrings.

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you have cases in which there are parentheses with something to keep? It will be more efficient to handle a generic case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try regex replace and regex or condition: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html
https://www.ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/or-in-regex/

```
l = ['(motor)', '(Eletro)', '(Defletor)', '( 56)']
l = [s.replace('(', '\(').replace(')', '\)') for s in l]
regex_str = f"({'|'.join(l)})"
df['code'] = df['code'].str.replace(regex_str, '', regex=True)
```

The `regex_str` will end up with something like

```
"(\(motor\)|\(Eletro\)|\(Defletor\)|\( 56\))"
```

Comment: I need to pass the list as an argument, how can I?

Comment: Do you just want to remove those strings in the list or any strings that's within parenthesis?

Comment: Only the string in the list

Comment: why do you need to pass the list as an argument? Can you explain why that is?

Comment: @JoãoFelipeHolanda in that case, you and create the regex string with "or" condition based on the list and use that for replace

Comment: Because I have a lot of information to remove from string in dataframe column

Comment: @PinyiWang I had this error: missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 2

Comment: yeah I forgot the escape the parenthesis in the input list. You'll need to replace all "(" and ")" with "\(" and "\)" respectively.

Comment: @JoãoFelipeHolanda just found out I added extra parenthesis, I edited the answer

Comment: Very good, the resolution was brilliant and very performative, it was very fast

Answer (score 0):

str.replace will work with one string not a list of strings.. you could probably loop through it

```
rmlist = ['(motor)', '(Eletro)', '(Defletor)', '(Eletro)', '( 56)']
for repl in rmlist:
    df['code'] = df['code'].str.replace(repl, '')
```

alternatively if your bracketed substring is at the end.. split it at "("
and discard additional column generated..will be faster for sure

```
df["code"]=df["code"].str.split(pat="(",n=1,expand=True)[0]
```

str.split is reasonably fast

Comment: the dataframe is too big to loop, so I'm looking for a method or a function

Comment: str.replace is a vectorised implementation ..considerably faster than any other...
alternatively why not just split at "("  whatever afte opening brace can be ignored

Comment: you can use apply with a lambda function..but that will be very heavy for a big dataframe

Comment: and Regex is atleast 10x slower than string replacement...regex not good for large dataframes. avoid Regex if possible with large dataframes if you need some speed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain any and all rows follow the format provided, you could attempt the following by using a lambda function:

```
df['code_clean'] = df['code'].apply(lambda x: x.split('(')[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the regular expression match method:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.match

```
df['code'] = df['code'].apply(lambda x: re.match(r'^(\w+)\(\w+\)',x).group(1))
```

The first part of the regular expression `^(\w+)`, creates a capturing group of any letters or numbers before encountering a parenthesis. The `group(1)` then extracts the text.